# Using same workspace for Java and Java EE in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, installation

I just installed Eclipse; both Java and Java EE. But when it prompted me for workspace, I ended up using the same directory for both of them, eclipse-workspace. Is this wrong or is it fine? If it is incorrect to do this, how do I fix it?

Comment: I have many projects in the same workspace, some java some java web/ee. No issues.

Comment: It's perfectly OK. The implementation of Java that a project uses depends on the project, not the entire workspace, so you should be fine.